# Filling missing values with groupby object on Pandas - Titanic dataset

Tags: python, pandas

I've already seen similar questions but none of them is an answer to mine or I didn't see/understand. I am a newbie in ML, and trying to discover numpy, pandas with known datasets on Kaggle. Currently, I am on Titanic dataset. I have 2 distinct dataset: train and test. I have to fill missing values on "Age" column of both train and test datasets. My criteria is a grouped object I created with train dataset. I am grouping with "Sex", "Pclass", and "Title"(comes from title of every passengers name).

```
grouped = train.groupby(["Sex","Title","Pclass"])
grouped_m = grouped.median()
grouped_m = grouped_m.reset_index()[["Sex","Title","Pclass", "Age"]]
```

Output is:

```
    Sex    Title  Pclass   Age
0   female     Miss       1  30.0
1   female     Miss       2  24.0
2   female     Miss       3  18.0
3   female      Mrs       1  40.0
4   female      Mrs       2  32.0
5   female      Mrs       3  31.0
6   female  Officer       1  49.0
7   female  Royalty       1  40.5
8     male   Master       1   4.0
9     male   Master       2   1.0
10    male   Master       3   4.0
11    male       Mr       1  40.0
12    male       Mr       2  31.0
13    male       Mr       3  26.0
14    male  Officer       1  51.0
15    male  Officer       2  46.5
16    male  Royalty       1  40.0
```

This is my criteria to apply on "Age" column of "test" dataset. For ex: when a row on test dataset with  Sex = Female, Title = Miss, Pclass = 1, Age = NaN, Nan value must be filled with output that above, which should be Age = 30.

Before filling:

```
train["Age"].isna().sum()
```

Output is:

```
177
```

I tried this:

```
train["Age"] = train["Age"].fillna(grouped["Age"].transform("median"))
```

It perfectly filled NaN values on train set.

After filling:

```
train["Age"].isna().sum()
```

Output is:

```
0
```

But when I apply this on test dataset, it changes nothing at all and didn't give any errors. 
Before filling:

```
test["Age"].isna().sum()
```

Output is:

```
86
```

Then I apply the function with group object that I created on train dataset:

```
test["Age"] = test["Age"].fillna(grouped["Age"].transform("median"))
test["Age"].isna().sum()
```

Output is:

```
86
```

NaN values still there on test dataset. How should I apply this function to change NaN values on test dataset with my grouped object which I created with train dataset ?

Comment: `grouped` is from grouping `train` so the index only aligns with rows in the `train` set when you transform and it wont be able to fill anything in the `test` set. You can either fill before the split, or you'll need to merge on the values using the index of `grouped["Age"].median()`

Comment: Could you include code to reproduce your problem exactly?

Comment: @ALollz , I tried to combine train and test datasets as "combined". But still the result is same since as you said "grouped is from grouping train". My logic was to make a groupby object using train data and use that groupby object on test data since both train and test datasets have same column names.

Answer (score 0):

We want to fill in missing age data instead of just dropping the missing age data rows. One way to do this is by filling in the mean age of all the passengers (imputation).
check the average age by passenger class. For example:

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import seaborn as sns
    %matplotlib inline

    #Data visualization to see the age difference due to Passenger class
    plt.figure(figsize=(12, 7))
    sns.boxplot(x='Pclass',y='Age',data=train,palette='winter')

    def impute_age(cols):
        Age = cols[0]
        Pclass = cols[1]

        if pd.isnull(Age):

            if Pclass == 1:
                return 37

            elif Pclass == 2:
                return 29

            else:
                return 24

        else:
            return Age
    train['Age'] = train[['Age','Pclass']].apply(impute_age,axis=1)#filling the missing values
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
I merged the data using DataFrame.merge() method as @ALollz suggests and apparently is works. Here's the code:

```
# First filling NaN on train set as I did before.
grouped = train.groupby(["Sex","Title", "Pclass"])
grouped_m = grouped.median().reset_index()[["Sex", "Title", "Pclass", "Age"]]
train["Age"] = train["Age"].fillna(grouped["Age"].transform("median"))

# Then used pd.DataFrame.merge() to apply the same grouped features on the test data.
med = train.groupby(['Sex', 'Pclass', 'Title'], 
                   as_index=False)['Age'].median()
test = test.merge(med, on=['Sex','Pclass','Title'], how='left', suffixes=('','_'))
test['Age'] = test['Age'].fillna(test.pop('Age_'))
```

Thank you everyone!